# solving the xpath property error even though xpath looks good

Tags: php, xpath, web-scraping

I tried to extract the version info from the webpage but I am getting an error even though XPath looks good on the HTML page.

code I tried is

```
use DOMDocument;
use DOMXPath;
function getVersionFromDownloads(string $url): string
{
    // support only windows
    $content = $this->fetch($url);
    $curl = curl_init($url);

    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FRESH_CONNECT, true);
    $content = curl_exec($curl);
    curl_close($curl);

    $dom = new DOMDocument();
    @$dom->loadHTML($content);

    $xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);

    $result = $xpath->query("//a[contains(text(),'paint.net')]");

    $header = $result->item(0)->textContent;
    echo $header;

}
getVersionFromDownloads('https://www.dotpdn.com/downloads/pdn.html');
```

The desired result is `4.2.10`

when I checked in the HTML page XPath looks to be good and it is showing the correct element. but when I tried to extract the text content it gives an error.

error given statement: `$header = $result->item(0)->textContent;`

Comment: Is the dom too large to provide here?  Can you `var_dump($result->item(0));`?

Comment: @mickmackusa it gives `NULL`. there sees to be something in xpath->query. but in inspect element it shows correct element only.

Comment: I think there may be something wrong with your curl/fetch.  https://3v4l.org/23HvD  we expect you, ad a developer, to isolate the earliest point of breakage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While testing my solutions, I was getting a lot of DOM errors using `$dom->load()`.  You can see all of the invalid markup using an online html validator such as https://www.freeformatter.com/html-validator.html.
This program was barking about many minor decprecations and then a few notable items like:

> Malformed byte sequence: “a9”.

and

> Malformed byte sequence: “ae”.

When I tried to script my own php code with `$dom->loadHTML()`...

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$dom->load('https://www.dotpdn.com/downloads/pdn.html');
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
return libxml_get_last_error();
```

I printed the return value to screen with `var_export()` to see:

> LibXMLError::__set_state(array( 'level' => 3, 'code' => 77, 'column' => 8, 'message' => 'Premature end of data in tag html line 1 ', 'file' => 'https://www.dotpdn.com/downloads/pdn.html', 'line' => 153, ))

---

**RECOMMENDED**

So instead of using `load()`, I decided to try `file_get_contents($url)` to get the source code and feed it to the DOM parser.

```
function getVersionFromDownloads($url)
{
    $dom = new DOMDocument();
    $dom->loadHTML(file_get_contents($url));
    $xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
    $text = $xpath->query("//a[contains(text(),'paint.net')]")->item(0)->textContent;
    return preg_replace('/paint\.net\s+/', '', $text);
}
var_export(getVersionFromDownloads('https://www.dotpdn.com/downloads/pdn.html'));
```

Output:

```
'4.2.10'
```

- To remove the single quotes, use `echo` instead of `var_export()`.  I only used it to demonstrate that there is no leading or trailing whitespace.
- `preg_replace()` is used before returning so that `paint.net` followed by multiple consecutive whitespaces inside the string are removed.
- For the record, this extraction technique will work the same:

  ```
   $xpath->query("//a[contains(text(),'paint.net')]/text()")->item(0)->nodeValue;
  ```
- In your:

  ```
   function getVersionFromDownloads(string $url): string
  ```

  the `: string` demands that a string value is returned from your function, but you are merely echoing -- be sure to return a string value.

Answer (score 0):

```
 $result = explode(" ",trim($xpath->query("//b/a")[0]->nodeValue))[1];
```

is that what you are looking for?

Comment: This is definitely not the solution.  The OP isn't struggling with the query, it is the fetching of the DOM before this.

Comment: Using the OP's query on properly a retrieved DOM string works -- so the problem is not the query.  Even if this answer did fix the problem (and it doesn't), it doesn't clean up the output which it is clearly trying to do.  Proof: https://3v4l.org/tHWR6  Plus this is a Code-only answer -- all answers should be explained